# Action Editor messes up whole values

Tags: animation, actions

It's a really odd issue. I made some animations for a model's skeleton. I created multiple animations though the action editor, however some extra actions were unintentionally automatically created for some of the model's meshes and whetever i select one of these the whole model get messed up (scaled like 50 times and randomly rotated). Even if I choose one of the working actions, it is still messed up.

Strangely one of my animations i created for the skeleton also has this issue.

Something i have to note, the blender file was originally created in Blender v2.78 but only the model with its skeleton, i later opened the file with Blender 2.80.75 to create the animations.

Comment: when you create actions, keyframes all the bones at frame 0 (or 1) otherwise the bones will inherit the keyframe they got from the previous action, it may be your problem here

Comment: Can clear transforms with Alt-G (location) R & S  After which only keyframed transforms will show.   Another tip is make a zero action _ie_ keyframe the rest pose, save as pose or action and set to clear.  (or as commented above,  a full set in first frame)

Comment: How I hope someone would make an in-depth tutorial explaining the intricacies of this. The only tutorials I've found would only explain the concept and nothing about all the pitfalls, which the NLA still seem very ridden of (3.5.1).